# How can I remove these two old versions of Firefox snap?

Tags: snap

I have Firefox installed and have set a limit for only up to two versions of each snap to be installed. However, and it's not the first time this happened to me on a machine with Ubuntu, there are two other older (soo older) versions installed there. And I can't remove them. The last time I did it using "sudo rm", the machine always needed to boot those two virtual disks and gave an error. It wasn't a critical error, but the message always appeared at the start of booting the machine.

Does anyone know what the normal procedure would be to remove these two versions?
[image]

[image]

Just to clarify it. These snaps are located at "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/"

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for a Firefox upgrade, and the older versions will get automatically removed.

To delete them now, you need to run `sudo snap remove firefox --revision=2760` and now the same command, but replace "2760" with "2645". You now removed the versions you didn't want.

You can also use this script to remove every previous version of every snap:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Removes old revisions of snaps
# CLOSE ALL SNAPS BEFORE RUNNING THIS
set -eu

LANG=C snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
    while read snapname revision; do
        snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
    done
```

The script tells you in a comment to close all snaps before running it, so if you're reading this from Firefox and want to run it, close it before proceeding.

Comment: "sudo snap set system refresh.retain=N", N can't be less than 2, and as I said in my post, I already did that.

"sudo snap remove firefox --revision=2760" this doesn't work, it says "revision 2645 of snap "firefox" is not installed".

And that script you wrote came from https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-remove-old-snap-versions-to-free.html and yes, I already did that too.

Comment: @Noctis Oh, I missed that part. Edited my answer now.
If you tried the script that would mean that the files in the picture should be removed, so the error `revision 2645 of snap "firefox" is not installed` makes sense.
If I'm correct you took that picture from Disk Usage Analyzer, so you have to re-scan if you still see the files (and the older versions), and if you still see even after a re-scan, reboot your computer.

Comment: Nop, they are still there. I checked it via Nautilus. I edited my post to show it.

Comment: Did you reboot? Try running `sudo apt autoremove`

Delete them manually if these don't work. Maybe in the future when you update Firefox, they will be automatically removed. If it doesn't, you probably messed something up by deleting them manually initially, and you have to continue deleting manually.

Comment: I didn't delete anything manually except the script thing. My problem in the first place is the fact that these two whatever snaps are there when I searched it to see I have 4 Firefox version. I didn't do anything in that point. Since then, I have been looking at how to eliminate it. Without deleting them manually because I already did it once on another terminal and every time the system booted, a message appeared that it was not possible to mount this virtual disk (in this case, the old version of Firefox). Since I see that I won't find help here, I'll go to the Snap forum.